Unable to programatically enable Audio Enhancements or set Audio DSP properties
I created a Visual Studio C++ console test project where I want to programatically set the voice capture DSP properties for the default microphone that I am using to record audio with. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/voicecapturedmo
However, even though the code doesn't return any errors I don't hear a difference in the recorded audio. For example, I should hear a noticable difference in noise level when switching noise cancellation off, but recording with NS on or off sounds the same.
Am I wrong to assume that a program can modify the properties of the microphone audio recording path used in a different program (like Audacity). If I manually turn audio enhancements ON or OFF via the Windows audio settings then I can clearly hear a difference.
Here is the code:
   HRESULT TestEnableAudioEnhancements()
  {

    HRESULT hr;
    PROPVARIANT var;
    IMediaObject* pDMO = NULL;
    IPropertyStore* pPS = NULL;
    IPropertyStore* pPropertyStore = NULL;

    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pDeviceEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice* pDevice = NULL;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CWMAudioAEC, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMediaObject, (void**)&pDMO);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }
    hr = pDMO->QueryInterface(IID_IPropertyStore, (void**)&pPS);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the device enumerator
    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&pDeviceEnumerator);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("%x\n", hr);
    }

    // Get the default audio endpoint
    hr = pDeviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eCapture, eCommunications, &pDevice);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("%x\n", hr);
    }

    // Get the property store
    hr = pDevice->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READWRITE, &pPropertyStore);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("%x\n", hr);
    }

    // Get the friendly name of the device
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    hr = pPropertyStore->GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &var);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        std::wstring deviceNameW(var.pwszVal);
        std::string deviceName = ConvertWStringToString(deviceNameW);
        printf("Device Friendly Name: %s\n", deviceName.c_str());
        PropVariantClear(&var);
    }



    // MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_DMO_SOURCE_MODE is true (Source mode)
    // In source mode, the application does not need to send input data to the DSP, 
    // because the DSP automatically pulls data from the audio devices.
    // For more information: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/medfound/voicecapturedmo.md

   #if 0
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_BOOL;
    var.boolVal = VARIANT_FALSE; // Enable the feature mode
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPropertyStore, PKEY_AudioEndpoint_Disable_SysFx, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);
    #endif


    // Set and verify MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_SYSTEM_MODE
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_I4;
    var.lVal = 0; // AEC only
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPS, MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_SYSTEM_MODE, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);

    // Set and verify MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATURE_MODE
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_BOOL;
    var.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE; // Enable the feature mode
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPS, MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATURE_MODE, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);

    // Set and verify MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_ECHO_LENGTH
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_I4;
    var.lVal = 512; // Echo length (tail length) in milliseconds
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPS, MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_ECHO_LENGTH, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);

    // Set and verify MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_NS
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_I4;
    var.lVal = 0;
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPS, MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_NS, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);

    // Set and verify MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_NOISE_FILL
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_BOOL;
    var.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE; // Enable noise fill
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPS, MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_NOISE_FILL, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);

    // Set and verify MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_CENTER_CLIP
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_BOOL;
    var.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE; // Enable center clip
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPS, MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_CENTER_CLIP, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);

    // Set and verify MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_AES
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_I4;
    var.lVal = 2; // Perform AES twice (to suppress non-linear echo residuals)
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPS, MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_AES, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);

    // Set and verify MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_AGC
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_BOOL;
    var.boolVal = VARIANT_FALSE; // Disable AGC
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPS, MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_AGC, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);

    // Set and verify MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_MIC_GAIN_BOUNDER
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_BOOL;
    var.boolVal = VARIANT_FALSE; // Example value for mic gain bounder
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPS, MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_MIC_GAIN_BOUNDER, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);

    // Set and verify MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_VAD
    PropVariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_I4;
    var.lVal = 1; // Example value for VAD mode
    SET_AND_VERIFY_PROPERTY(pPS, MFPKEY_WMAAECMA_FEATR_VAD, var);
    PropVariantClear(&var);

    if (NULL != pDMO) {
        pDMO->Release();
    }

    if (NULL != pPS) {
        pPS->Release();
    }

    return S_OK;
     }

